# SQL Query optimization without Not In and In using joins

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a query like below which I want to re-write using joins. This query is taking 4-5hrs to execute in production and returning GBs of data. 
To restructure it, I checked its execution plan with a small data set in my local DB which shows cost as 782.
On this, my peers suggest that we should not use IN and NOT IN in this query to improve its performance.

Note:: sub query below `"SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150"` is just to try in local, so that I can get some data in IN clause. Actual sub-query is without ROWNUM and some clauses in where condition.
Original Query 1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                a1.fk_id
            FROM
                tableA a1
            WHERE a1.master_id IN (
                       SELECT DISTINCT
                            a2.master_ref
                        FROM
                            tableB a2
                        WHERE a2.pk_id IN ( SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150)                            
                    ) 
                     AND a1.fk_id NOT IN ( SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150)
```

I re-wrote it again as follows which gives me the same output with cost in execution plan as 114.

Query 2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a1.fk_id
  FROM
      tableA a1, tableB a2 
  WHERE a1.master_id = a2.master_ref 
  AND a2.pk_id IN ( 
    (SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150)
    )
  AND a1.fk_id NOT IN (
    (SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150)
  ) -- This query gives correct result as above.
```

But as I wanted to avoid IN and NOT IN clauses completely and want to use JOIN wherever possible. I tried few more queries using JOIN/LEFT JOIN/EXISTS/NOT EXISTS, but everytime my output is different from what is required.

One of the queries which I have tried is as below :

Query 3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a1.fk_id 
  FROM
      tableA a1, ( SELECT a3.pk_id FROM tableB a3 WHERE ROWNUM <= 150 ) pkgObjs, tableB a2
  WHERE a1.ida3b5 = a2.master_ref 
  AND a2.master_id = pkgObjs.pk_id  
  AND a1.fk_id <> pkgObjs.pk_id;
 -- This query is not giving me intended results.
```

I have a few questions related to this::

1) Why my 3rd query(using joins) are not giving me appropriate results? -- logically it seems to be same

2) Is IN and NOT IN in such case have any other alternatives, should we avoid it completely?

3) Is 2nd Query is still costly in terms of performance?

I am new to SQL and trying to analyze all possible scenarios. It would be great if I can get some help in writing this query using joins.

Comment: **First** testing with subquery using `ROWNUM <= 150` has no expected result, as you use random  150 rows from the table. **Second** there is not such thing as *a query without `IN` and `NOT IN` is always better that with them*. You must investigate the problem in the productive execution plan and react.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To nullify the probability of random values due to ROWNUM, I have created a temp_table with 50000 records. Now, as I am using temp_table instead of ROWNUM subquery I can see a considerable performance improvement. Earlier with 50000 records query was taking 140 secs to execute, with temp_table it is only taking 12 sec. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, this is the simplest query you can use:

```
SELECT
    A.FK_ID
FROM
    TABLEA A, TABLEB B
WHERE
    A.PK_ID = B.PK_ID
    AND A.FK_ID <> B.PK_ID
    --AND ROWNUM <= 150
```

Note that `ROWNUM` is commented because without ordering, you can't trust it's results.

If the execution plan is costly, you need to analyze indexing, and sometimes a small change like the next, makes a great difference:

```
SELECT
    B.FK_ID
FROM
    TABLEA B, TABLEB A
WHERE
    B.PK_ID = A.PK_ID
    AND B.PK_ID <> A.FK_ID
```